# How to get "no rows" error when execute raw SQL with NPGSQL?

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, npgsql

I'm new to C# so I apologize if this is an obvious question but I can't seem to find an answer to it. I'm writing a client application that takes a raw SQL command and passes it directly to the database.  I don't know if it will be an `select`, `update`, `insert`, or `delete`.  If it's a `select`, I want to get the results into a `DataTable`.  If it's anything else, I want to know if it was successful or if there was an error in execution (for example: no rows were affected).

I am current doing the below code before I found out it doesn't return any errors for `update` or `delete` affects no rows.  I formatted the code but tried to leave enough to understand what I am trying to do.  Since this is my first question on here, if you have any tips on how better to contextualise my questions, please share.

```
class Client
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Config.LoadConfig();
        Db.Init();

        var testQuery1 = "select * from test where 1=1";
        var testQuery2 = "update test set value='value3' where name = 'name3'";
        var testQuery3 = "insert into test (id, name, value, date) values (4,'name4','value4',current_timestamp)";

        Db.Query(testQuery1);
        Db.PrintResults();

        Db.Query(testQuery2);
        Db.PrintResults();

        Db.Query(testQuery3);
        Db.PrintResults();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Universal database class.
/// </summary>
public static partial class Db
{
    private static IUniversalDatabase _dbUniConn;

    /* Database Results */
    public static string ErrorCode { get; private set; }
    public static string ErrorMessage { get; private set; }
    public static int RowCount { get; private set; }
    public static double ExecutionSeconds { get; private set; }
    public static DataTable Data { get; private set; } = new DataTable();

    public static void Init(string connString, Type dbType)
    {
        try
        {
            _connString = connString;
            _connType = dbType;

            switch (_connType)
            {
                case Db.Type.PostgreSQL:
                    _dbUniConn = new PostgresDatabase(_connString);
                    break;
                ...
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Open()
    { ...  _dbUniConn.Open(); ...  }

    public static void Close()
    { ...  _dbUniConn.Close(); ...  }

    public static void Query(string cmdString)
    {
        var start = DateTime.Now;

        Open();

        /* Reset Data */
        Data.Reset();
        RowCount = 0;
        ErrorMessage = "";
        ErrorCode = "";

        /* Execute Query */
        _dbUniConn.Query(cmdString);

        /* Execution Time */
        ExecutionSeconds = (DateTime.Now - start).TotalSeconds;
        Debug.Write("Database:    Execution Time: " + ExecutionSeconds.ToString() + " seconds", Debug.TraceLevel.Info);

        /* RowCount and Error Message */
        RowCount = Data.Rows.Count;
        Debug.Write("Database:    Returning " + RowCount.ToString() + " rows", Debug.TraceLevel.Info);
        Debug.Write("Database:    Error (" + ErrorCode + "): " + ErrorMessage, Debug.TraceLevel.Info);

        Close();
    }

    public class PostgresDatabase : IUniversalDatabase
    {
        private NpgsqlConnection _dbConn;

        public PostgresDatabase(string connString)
        { _dbConn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString); }

        public void Open()
        { _dbConn.Open(); }

        public void Close()
        { _dbConn.Close(); }

        public void Dispose()
        { _dbConn.Dispose(); }

        public void Query(string cmdString)
        {
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(cmdString, _dbConn);
            NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

            try
            {
                da.Fill(Data);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MatchCollection configVar = Regex.Matches(e.Message.ToString(), @"^(?<code>.*?): (?<msg>.*?)$");
                foreach (Match match in configVar)
                {
                    ErrorCode = match.Groups["code"].Value.ToString();
                    ErrorMessage = match.Groups["msg"].Value.ToString();
                }
            }
            da.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I should have made this part more clear.  I guess the point is that I'm not able to get any error messages when an insert/update/delete fails for whatever reason.  When I run an `update` where it should not affect any rows or an `insert` which has bad data, I want to get the DB errors in my `ErrorCode` and `ErrorMessage` but I see no such thing.

Comment: Since this seems to be "test - sort of", why not do some auditing, i.e. during update run "insert before into audit table", then "insert after".  Then you will know the meaning of "da feet" - I mean, you will know if it hit the database.

Comment: I've updated my question to be more on point of "no rows" for `update` and `delete`.  I'm not familiar with "insert before into audit table".  I'll have to look into that.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20050210221505.GA73565%40winnie.fuhr.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding `RETURNING 1` to my query when it started with anything but `select`:

```
        public void Query()
        {
            Match m = Regex.Match(QueryInput.queryString, @"^\s*(?i:select).*$");
            if (!m.Success)
            {
                QueryInput.queryString += " RETURNING 1";
            }

            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(QueryInput.queryString, _dbConn);
            NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

            try
            {
                da.Fill(Data);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                m = Regex.Match(e.Message.ToString(), @"^(?<code>.*?): (?<msg>.*?)$");
                if (m.Success)
                {
                    ErrorCode = m.Groups["code"].Value.ToString();
                    ErrorMessage = m.Groups["msg"].Value.ToString();
                }
                else
                    throw e;
            }
            da.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

I tested this with the following:

```
            Db.Query("update test set value = 'value1' where name in (\nselect name from test where name = 'name1')", Db.Type.PostgreSQL);
            Db.PrintResults();

            Db.Query("\nSELECT * from test limit 10", Db.Type.PostgreSQL);
            Db.PrintResults();

            Db.Query("update test set value='new value' where name='name1'", Db.Type.PostgreSQL);
            Db.PrintResults();

            Db.Query("insert into test (id,name,value,date) values (3,'name3',value3,current_timestamp)", Db.Type.PostgreSQL);
            Db.PrintResults();

            Db.Query("delete from test where id = 3", Db.Type.PostgreSQL);
            Db.PrintResults();
```

This returned the following results:

```
13:43:57:014 - Info  - Database: Received [PostgreSQL] command (update test set value = 'value1' where name in (
select name from test where name = 'name1'))
13:43:57:015 - Debug - Database: Connection is now opened.
13:43:57:070 - Info  - Database:    Execution Time: 0.055539 seconds
13:43:57:071 - Info  - Database:    Returning 1 rows
13:43:57:071 - Info  - Database:    Error (0): Success.
13:43:57:071 - Debug - Database: Connection is now closed.
13:43:57:072 - Debug - Database: Result      ?column?
13:43:57:072 - Debug - Database: Result   1: 1

13:43:57:072 - Info  - Database: Received [PostgreSQL] command (
SELECT * from test limit 10)
13:43:57:072 - Debug - Database: Connection is now opened.
13:43:57:088 - Info  - Database:    Execution Time: 0.0160114 seconds
13:43:57:088 - Info  - Database:    Returning 2 rows
13:43:57:088 - Info  - Database:    Error (0): Success.
13:43:57:089 - Debug - Database: Connection is now closed.
13:43:57:089 - Debug - Database: Result      id        name      value     date
13:43:57:089 - Debug - Database: Result   1: 1         name1     value1    6/14/2017 8:37:48 PM
13:43:57:089 - Debug - Database: Result   2: 2         name2     value2    6/14/2017 8:37:48 PM

13:43:57:089 - Info  - Database: Received [PostgreSQL] command (update test set value='new value' where name='name1')
13:43:57:089 - Debug - Database: Connection is now opened.
13:43:57:090 - Info  - Database:    Execution Time: 0.0010007 seconds
13:43:57:090 - Info  - Database:    Returning 1 rows
13:43:57:091 - Info  - Database:    Error (0): Success.
13:43:57:092 - Debug - Database: Connection is now closed.
13:43:57:093 - Debug - Database: Result      ?column?
13:43:57:093 - Debug - Database: Result   1: 1

13:43:57:094 - Info  - Database: Received [PostgreSQL] command (insert into test (id,name,value,date) values (3,'name3',value3,current_timestamp))
13:43:57:096 - Debug - Database: Connection is now opened.
13:43:57:186 - Info  - Database:    Execution Time: 0.0920653 seconds
13:43:57:187 - Info  - Database:    Returning 0 rows
13:43:57:191 - Info  - Database:    Error (42703): column "value3" does not exist
13:43:57:192 - Debug - Database: Connection is now closed.
13:43:57:199 - Debug - Database: Result

13:43:57:200 - Info  - Database: Received [PostgreSQL] command (delete from test where id = 3)
13:43:57:201 - Debug - Database: Connection is now opened.
13:43:57:204 - Info  - Database:    Execution Time: 0.0040029 seconds
13:43:57:204 - Info  - Database:    Returning 0 rows
13:43:57:205 - Info  - Database:    Error (-1403): No rows found.
13:43:57:205 - Debug - Database: Connection is now closed.
13:43:57:206 - Debug - Database: Result      ?column?
```